# Debugging Firefox extension - How to see all JS and XUL files contained in the XPI?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-addon, xpi

I'm trying to debug a Firefox extension, using Firefox 28.0.

I have set up the dev environment as suggested in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment (actually I just took the lazy way out and installed the DevPrefs extension to set all the necessary about:configs)

I then open Firefox and go into the debugging environment (Tools > Web Developer > Browser Toolbox).

I then go to the Debugger tab.

However, under the Sources pane, under my extension (e.g. chrome://myextension), I only see some of the JS and XUL files that are contained in my extension XPI.

How can I manually "load files" in the debugger, so that I can set a breakpoint and trace the runtime of my extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The debugger doesn't have any functionality that would allow loading files "manually", instead it will show you every file that is currently loaded by the JavaScript engine. If you dig into details, this means that whenever the JavaScript engine compiles a new script the debugger is notified and adds the corresponding file to its list. So normally all you need to do is open a page or dialog that uses that script and it will become visible in the debugger. I say "normally" because in my tests this didn't seem to work reliably - there appears to be some bug which makes the debugger miss out some scripts, maybe that's what prompted your question.

Now of course you can consider faking the notification to force the debugger to load a particular file - e.g. if you want to set breakpoints before the file actually loads. I tried it and it is indeed possible, but it requires you to mess with Firefox internals and it relies on a number of implementation details that might change in future Firefox versions. In particular, you need to get the `DebuggerServer` instance used to communicate with the debugger. While the in-process debugger always uses the same instance which is trivial to get, a new instance is created for each remote debugger. From what I can tell, getting to that instance is only possible with the changes implemented in [bug 993029](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=993029) which means that it will only work with Firefox 32 (currently available from the [Firefox Aurora channel](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/channel/#aurora)) and above.

The problem is that the `DebuggerServer` instance is being created by the `BrowserToolboxProcess` class declared in [ToolboxProcess.jsm](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/a74600665875/browser/devtools/framework/ToolboxProcess.jsm). Before the changes introduced by bug 993029 a `BrowserToolboxProcess` object would be created and no reference to it kept - meaning that it would be impossible to access it and the corresponding connection after the fact. Starting with Firefox 32 all created `BrowserToolboxProcess` objects are stored in the `processes` [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and can be enumerated.

This code can be used to fake a [Debugger.onNewScript() call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JS_Debugger_API_Reference/Debugger#onNewScript%28%29) that will be forwarded to the remote debugger:

```
(function()
{
  // Iterate over existing processes
  const {processes} = Cu.import("resource:///modules/devtools/ToolboxProcess.jsm", null);
  for (var process of processes)
  {
    // Iterate over connections associated with each process
    var debuggerServer = process.debuggerServer;
    for (var connID in debuggerServer._connections)
    {
      if (!debuggerServer._connections.hasOwnProperty(connID))
        continue;
      var conn = debuggerServer._connections[connID];

      // Get ChromeDebuggerActor instance for the connection
      var chromeDebugger = conn._getOrCreateActor(conn.rootActor._extraActors.chromeDebugger.actorID);

      // Fake new script call
      chromeDebugger.onNewScript({
        url: "chrome://myextension/content/script.js", // CHANGE THAT LINE
        source: {text:""},
        getChildScripts: () => []
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

As mentioned above, this code should only work starting with Firefox 32, I tested it on Firefox 33.0a1. You can run it from Scratchpad, make sure to [switch environment to "Browser"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Scratchpad#Running_Scratchpad_in_the_browser_context). There is no guarantee whatsoever that it will continue working in future Firefox versions, there are several implementation details used here that can change at any time.

Comment: not the definite answer that I'd hoped for, but does tell me the technical details that I need to know, and why the debugger behaves in that way. And I think it deserves the bounty.